Using PageFactory to initialize Custom WebElements
Currently I am writing End-To-End Tests with Selenium + Cucumber in Java. I wanted to write CustomWebElements and try to access them in my Pages.
My Problem is, that my list (customCards) in CustomPage is null. Is there something wrong in the pagefactory?
public class CustomPage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//app-custom-card")
    private List<CustomCard> customCards;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//app-custom-list//div//p")
    private WebElement header;

    public CustomPage (WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public int getNumberOfCustomCards() {
        return customCards.size();
    }
}

public class CustomCardextends CustomWebElement {

    private final WebElement element;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//mat-card-title")
    private WebElement title;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//mat-card-content/span")
    private WebElement content;

    public CustomCard(WebElement element) {
        super(Driver.getDriver());
        this.element= element;
    }

public abstract class CustomWebElement {

    private final WebDriver webDriver;

    private final By locator;

    public CustomWebElement(WebDriver webDriver, By locator) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
        this.locator = locator;
    }

    public CustomWebElement(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
        this.locator = null;
    }

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }

    public By getLocator() {
        return locator;
    }

}

The XPath is correct, it also finds the header attribute.
